# How to match line colour with legend?

Tags: r, visualization, echarts4r

I'm manually entering the line colour in echarts4r - how can the legend match this line colour?

```
 library(echarts4r)

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(50),
  y = rnorm(50, 10, 3)
)

df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_line(y, showSymbol = FALSE, lineStyle = list(color = "green"))
```

The output is below - the legend shows red, the line is green.

[image]

Comment: Try this instead for setting the color: `e_line(y, showSymbol = FALSE, color = "green")`

Answer (score 1):

Well late to this but `e_color` is easier

library(echarts4r)

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(50),
  y = rnorm(50, 10, 3)
)

df %>% 
  e_charts(x) %>% 
  e_line(y, showSymbol = FALSE) %>%
  e_color("green")
```